# How can i bring up the iPhone call screen

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I allow my user to select phone numbers in my application.  How can I then bring up the iPhone call screen  and then if possible, initiate the phone call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to recreate the dial screen within your application (didn't take too long for me to do.)  Once you have the phone number entered, you'll need to initiate the phone call by doing:

```
NSString* theNumberYouGathered = @"9994441234";
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormatting: @"tel:%s", theNumberYouGathered]]];
```

Note this will only work on the actual phone, and not the simulator.

To create the dialer screen you'll need to:

- Create a xib file with a set of `UIButton`s (for #s 1-9), a `UILabel` to show the currently entered number, and a "Call" button.
- Hook up the presses on the number `UIButton`s and add the digit to a local variable `NSString` on your ViewController.  Update the `UILabel` with this number.
- When the call `UIButton` is pressed, take the locally stored # and place the aforementioned method call with it.

Comment: I'll test this now - but if this works I'll be very happy.

thanks for replying so promptly.

Comment: @WaterBoy:  I just updated the answer with some of the overview steps I took to create the dialer.  If you have any further questions, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:12125551212"]];
```

which will create a UIAlertView prompting the user to call the number or cancel.

Comment: Its not creating Uialertview

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code

```
 NSString *phoneNumber = @"18000275749"; // dynamically assigned
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"telprompt://%@",phoneNumber]]];
```