# Customize iPhone Dialer

Tags: iphone, ios4

Is there a way to customize the calling dialer interface of iphone to make calls and everything as that the iphone dialer supports by using a public API reference. If there is a way then can anyone please direct me to a proper link where I can read about it. I know

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://8005551212"]];
```

this helps to make a call but I want to not open the default interface which I don't want to open. I will appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

Regards,
Ankur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Vladimir says, this is not built in, so you'll need to build your own.

To do so is pretty easy:

1. Create a xib file with a set of `UIButton`s (for #s 1-9), a `UILabel` to show the currently entered number, and a "Call" button.

   - Hook up the presses on the number `UIButton`s and add the digit to a local variable `NSString` on your ViewController.  Update the `UILabel` with this number.
   - When the call `UIButton` is pressed, take the locally stored # and place the aforementioned method call with it.

Originally from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571790/how-can-i-bring-up-the-iphone-call-screen).

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no public interface for that. If you really need that feature you can try to [send](https://bugreport.apple.com/) bug report to Apple with a request for it.