# Using Dialer for iOS app

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can i bring up the iPhone call screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571790/how-can-i-bring-up-the-iphone-call-screen)

I need to use the Dialer in my iOS App, as shown in the below diagram. How can I customize/reuse the iPhone's dialer view?
[image]